# Postgresql Error - FATAL: unrecognized configuration parameter "default_text_search_config"

Tags: postgresql

I've just installed PostgreSQL yesterday and it ran fine with the exact same command:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data start -l /usr/local/pgsql/log/pgsql.log
```

However, when I tried to run it again today, it didn't work, and I found the following message in the log file:

```
FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "default_text_search_config"
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL? Where did the install files come from? Your OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That parameter is recognized since PostgreSQL 8.3. You must be installing **8.2** or older, which is unwise. It probably chokes on a config file from another installation in your PATH.

Current version is 9.1. Version 8.2 came out in 2006 (!), it reaches [end of life in 2011](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) (no more security upgrades). Install a more recent version.